# Re-Position material autocomplete popup icon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am looking for a way to add a custom button to the end of material autocomplete. The problem is that it seems popup icon is styled to be at the end of the autocomplete input.

[image]

This style cause something like below which prevents from putting a button at the end of autocomplete.

[image]

But I want something like below.

[image]

The way I am adding this button is by overriding endAdornment of autocomplete textfield.

```
renderInput={(params) => (
  <TextField
    {...params}
    label={label}
    variant="outlined"
    InputProps={{
      ...params.InputProps,
      endAdornment: (
        <>
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <IconButton icon="search" style={{ padding: '2px' }} />
          </InputAdornment>
          {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
        </>
      ),
    }}
  />
)}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Autocomplete` element inspected, you can see there is a huge `padding-left` applied to `Autocomplete-inputRoot` element that pushes away `TextField` element you're using as `renderInput`. Therefore, you need to override that padding. And to move the Autocomplete `popupIcon` you need to override the `left` css property

```
const Autocomplete = withStyles({
  inputRoot: {
    padding: "16px !important",

    '&[class*="MuiOutlinedInput-root"] .MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment': {
      left: 32, // probably the width of your search IconButton or more if needed
    },
  },
})(MuiAutocomplete);
```

**Please note that you can play with this style to achieve your best result**.